# How to ignite resistor with N-channel MOSFET?

Tags: resistors, mosfet-driver

I'm trying to ignite a 10 \$ \Omega \$ resistor with IRF530 MOSFET and 12V power supply. The problem is that the FET gets hot and the resistor is not burnt like when I fired it directly from the same power supply. Any suggestion please?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you connect the 3V3 input of the rightmost circuit shown to 12V?

Comment: Also please add a link to the datasheet of the transistor used.

Comment: Why'd you want to burn your resistor ? :) -Anyway, it's easiest if the resistor is a low Wattage resistor; don't connect a power resistor... Inspired by Sphero's answer: A STP55NF06 or STP65NF06 is low-cost and has a low RDSon. There are better MOSFETs in the STP series, but I think these would do nicely.

Comment: Here is the datasheet http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000699.pdf

Comment: @ PacMan, I will get both STP55NF06 or STP65NF06 to try and report back the result soon. Thanks.

Comment: @jamithaawawn - datasheets for the STP MOSFETs are here: [STP55NF06](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00002311.pdf) and [STP65NF06](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00126774.pdf). I bought a handful from [Tayda](http://www.taydaelectronics.com/) -Tayda does not seem to be ESD-savvy, but their prices are low.

Comment: Why are you showing the 10 Ohm resistor as a inductor?  You obviously know how to draw resistors as exhibited by the other two, so I don't get what you are trying to communicate by drawing the 10 Ohm resistor like a inductor. What the...?

Answer (score 3):

The IRF530 needs 10V to fully turn it on. Pick a better MOSFET- one that is guaranteed low Rds(on) with 3.3V on the gate.

Comment: Agreed, even more importantly than that though, the rated threshold voltage of the IRF530 can be anywhere between \$2\mathrm{V}\$ and \$4\mathrm{V}\$, so at \$3\mathrm{V}\$ the transistor will basically be barely be on.

Comment: Please can you suggest how to choose a suitable mosfet for this purpose.

Comment: @jamithaawawn - You look at the data sheet, and examine the current vs gate voltage curves.

Comment: The Rds(on) will be specified (guaranteed) at a voltage on the data sheet, make sure that voltage is 3.3V or less. The curves are 'typical' and should not be depended on.

Answer (score 1):

As has been remarked, you need a much higher gate voltage to ensure the FET turns on hard. There are a couple of ways to do this. First, you can use a level shifter to go from 3.3 to 12 volts. As an example, a MAX427 or MAX4427 non-inverting buffer is cheap and will do the job. If you have some NPN and PNP transistors on hand you can roll your own

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMKOOO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pretty much any small-signal transistor rated for more than 12 volts will do.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and pointers for my further diving into the world of mosfet. Have a good day.